# Combining uppercase and lowercase search option not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my application, I am trying to search combining words like Solar -> S is caps and others are small letters. In this condition, my search filter option is not working. Only working for small letters and capital letters. like `ABCS` and `abcd`. How to do for search option both uppercase and lowercase.

filter.pipe.ts:

```
return products.filter((items) => {
  return (
    items.product_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    items.product_content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
    items.product_name.toUpperCase().includes(searchText) ||
    items.product_content.toUpperCase().includes(searchText)
  );
});
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-7uau9m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpipes%2Ffilter.pipe.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
return products.filter((items) => {
    return (
        items.product_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) ||
        items.product_content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    );
});
```